# How can i get multiple keys from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

![enter image description here][1]

```
 mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Adapter_Hotels, Adapter_HotelsHolder>(mOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Adapter_HotelsHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Adapter_Hotels model) {

            String key = getRef(position).getKey();
            mRef1 = mRef.child(key).child("rooms");
            mRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        roomkey = child.getKey();
                    }
                    minmax.clear();
                    mRef2 = mRef1.child(roomkey).child("promos").child("regular").child(ym).child("price").child(guest);
                    mRef2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
```

Here is all of my queries. Is this advisable? It's totally working I removed all the codes for retrieving. My question is any other way to do this nicer or cleaner?

Comment: Please add the code that you are using.

Comment: @AlexMamo copied my current code

Comment: What is the problem with the code you shared? When you run through it in a debugger, what line of code doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @Frank There is no error but I cant get what I want which is the minimum values from all the child

Comment: I honestly don't really understand how too relate that to the code you shared. I recommend stepping through the code in a debugger, so that you see where it doesn't do what you expect it to do. You might want also want to consider making the sample smaller, also known as [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Btw: if you attach a listener like `mRef1.addValueEventListener` then all data under `mRef1` is already in the snapshot that you receive. So you should never have to attach another listener under `mRef` in the outermost `onDataChange` you shared.

Comment: What doesn't work about the code you now shared?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  It's working. I edited my post to my current code and if this is advisable? If not any recommendations on how to do it? I attached it inside the adapter so that i can still use the holder?

Comment: You're still adding a listener on a child of a reference (`mRef2`) for which you already have a dataSnapshot (`mRef1`). That's not needed because (as I said before), the `DataSnapshot` you get for `mRef1` already contains the data for `mRef2` too. It won't redownload the data (Firebase dedupes it under the hood), but it makes your code more complex than needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks a bit more complex than needed. As far as I can see you can accomplish the exact same with:

```
mRef1 = mRef.child(key).child("rooms");
mRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot roomSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            roomkey = child.getKey();
            DataSnapshot priceSnapshot = roomSnapshot.child(roomkey).child("promos").child("regular").child(ym).child("price").child(guest);
            System.out.println(priceSnapshot.getValue());
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Changes:

- Don't leave `onCancelled` empty, as undetected errors are really hard to troubleshoot.
- Put the lookup of the price inside the loop, so that it looks up prices for all rooms. If you're only looking for the price of one room, you should use a query to only read that single room.
- There is no need to use a separate listener for the price itself, as (as far as I can see) the price is already in the `dataSnapshot` for `rooms`.

Comment: It does'nt work tried using your code and setting       holder.hPrice.setText(" " + priceSnapshot.getValue()); the output is null

Comment: Btw, i need to get all the value from all the child and get the lowest number from it by using the code on my post I can already get it I just want to do it nice and clean

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
    Log.i("TAG", "child key = " + child.getKey());
}
```